# MS Live profile data: gender and birthday are always null

Tags: oauth, scope, live

I've authenticated user with MS Live oAuth2 api using "wl.basic,wl.birthday" scopes (which includes all the needed info as stated in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243646.aspx).

User has both gender and his birthday set on live.com user management page.

But when i'm trying to get user data with https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=*, i get JSON where gender and birthday (birth_year, birth_month, birth_day) are always null.

Do i need some different scope? Or MS doesn't return them at all?
Could it be that data isn't populated somehow, because i use freshly created user?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  My birthday was set in my Live Profile "Account Settings" (accessed via the top-right user menu next to my avatar), but the three birthday values were null in the OAuth response.

On my Live Profile page (profile.live.com), I noticed links to my Skype and Messenger profiles.  My birthday was already showing up in Skype, but not Messenger.  When I set my birthday in Messenger, birth_year/birth_month/birth_day were populated in the OAuth response.